# Join tables based on a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database I have the following three tables with the fields listed:

```
TablePS 

 aID 

TableAM 

 aID(pk)
 bID  

TableM 

 bID(pk)
 bName
```

If I know the aID in TablePS, how can I find the value of bName in TableM?
I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT bName FROM TableM WHERE bID=
(SELECT TablePS.aID,TableAM.aID 
FROM TablePS 
INNER JOIN TableAM 
ON TablePS.aID= TableAM.aID)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select bName
from tableM
    inner join tableAM on tableM.bID = tableAM.bID
where
    aID = [value]
```

should be sufficient.
If you need to join to table PS, then

```
select bName
from tableM
    inner join tableAM on tableM.bID = tableAM.bID
    inner join tablePS on tableAM.aID = tablePS.aID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select BName from TableM as M inner join TableAM as Am on M.bId=Am.bID
inner join TablePS as P on Am.Aid=P.Aid
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I'm taking a wild guess that John means "the query is not working". Looks ok though

Comment: @whytheq thanks, that really helps. What I was asking for was more specific information, since the query looks fine to me.

Comment: apologies @AaronBertrand; it's tricky sometimes on _SO_ trying to distinguish between brevity and sarcasm; I totally agree that the query looks fine. @John - would it be possible to expand on "not working query" with the error message you're receiving or some explanation of why you think it's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT k.bName 
FROM TablePS p 
     INNER JOIN TableAM m ON m.aID = p.aID
     INNER JOIN TableM k on k.bID = m.bID
```

Comment: any other way without inner join

Comment: @John what is wrong with an inner join, since that seems to be what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `JOIN`s then maybe this.

I've assumed aId is type INT which you can change.

```
declare @x as int = 10 --<<change to an id that you are searching for

 select bname from  TableM  where bid in 
            (
            select  bID from TableAM  
            where aID in 
                             (
                             select aID from TablePS where aId = @x
                             ) 
            )
```